How to fix x server not seeing display after reinstalling nvidia drivers
Graphical environment won't work after reinstalling nvidia drivers. Drivers are working. They are loaded and running but X server doesn't see any displays
After uninstalling driver, I've tried to install it from mhwd but it seemed like there was some files left over from previous installation so I've just installed all the packages for correct version using pacman.
Right now when i power on pc it stays on tty1 and doesn't start X Server.
I have access through tty and ssh.
Secure boot is disabled
This is the output of cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE
[   363.496] Current Operating System: Linux piotr-lenovo 6.10.13-3-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Oct  8 03:24:49 UTC 2024 x86_64
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[   363.522] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[   363.522] (EE) No devices detected.
[   363.522] (EE)
[   363.522] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[   363.522] (EE)
[   363.522] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   363.522] (EE)
[   363.538] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

Output of journalctl -xe | grep nvidia
lis 28 20:12:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
lis 28 20:12:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
lis 28 20:12:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
lis 28 20:12:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia: module license taints kernel.
lis 28 20:12:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 240
lis 28 20:12:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
lis 28 20:12:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
lis 28 20:12:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  550.135  Wed Nov 13 23:35:58 UTC 2024
lis 28 20:12:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
lis 28 20:12:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
lis 28 20:12:47 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
lis 28 20:12:47 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 234.
lis 28 20:12:44 piotr-lenovo systemd-modules-load[326]: Inserted module 'nvidia_uvm'
lis 28 20:14:20 piotr-lenovo sudo[1006]:    piotr : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/piotr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/modprobe -r nvidia
lis 28 20:14:25 piotr-lenovo sudo[1039]:    piotr : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/piotr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/modprobe nvidia
lis 28 20:15:23 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia-uvm: Unloaded the UVM driver.
lis 28 20:15:23 piotr-lenovo sudo[1170]:    piotr : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/piotr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/modprobe -r nvidia_uvm
lis 28 20:15:23 piotr-lenovo sudo[1187]:    piotr : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/piotr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/modprobe -r nvidia_modeset
lis 28 20:15:23 piotr-lenovo sudo[1200]:    piotr : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/piotr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/modprobe -r nvidia
lis 28 20:17:08 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
lis 28 20:17:08 piotr-lenovo kernel: nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 234.
lis 28 20:17:42 piotr-lenovo sudo[1304]:    piotr : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/piotr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nvidia-smi -pm ENABLED
lis 28 20:17:42 piotr-lenovo kernel: NVRM: Persistence mode is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use nvidia-persistenced instead.
lis 28 20:26:34 piotr-lenovo sudo[1975]:    piotr : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/piotr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl restart nvidia-persistenced
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nvidia-persistenced.service has begun execution
░░ A start job for unit nvidia-persistenced.service has begun execution.
lis 28 20:26:34 piotr-lenovo nvidia-persistenced[1981]: Started (1981)
░░ Subject: A start job for unit nvidia-persistenced.service has finished successfully
░░ A start job for unit nvidia-persistenced.service has finished successfully.
lis 28 20:27:10 piotr-lenovo sudo[2104]:    piotr : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/piotr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose
lis 28 20:27:10 piotr-lenovo nvidia-persistenced[2108]: Verbose syslog connection opened
lis 28 20:27:10 piotr-lenovo nvidia-persistenced[2108]: Directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced will not be removed on exit
lis 28 20:27:10 piotr-lenovo nvidia-persistenced[2108]: Failed to lock PID file: Resource temporarily unavailable
lis 28 20:27:10 piotr-lenovo nvidia-persistenced[2108]: Shutdown (2108)

Output of sudo dmesg | grep -i nvidia
[    1.949104] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.949114] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    1.949119] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.949120] nvidia: module license taints kernel.
[    2.599932] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 240
[    2.601330] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    2.601580] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    2.649512] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  550.135  Thu Nov 14 00:09:29 UTC 2024
[    2.683582] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  550.135  Wed Nov 13 23:35:58 UTC 2024
[    2.687399] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    2.687403] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   15.689465] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[   15.934168] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 234.
[   21.021923] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
[   21.021994] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16
[   21.022045] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input17
[   21.022088] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input18
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver                                   NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver                                   NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
[  174.861073] nvidia-uvm: Unloaded the UVM driver.
[  279.422243] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[  279.667412] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 234.
[  314.129911] NVRM: Persistence mode is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use nvidia-persistenced instead.
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
               NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver

